# How can I stop/resume jquery .animate() exactly where I left it?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, mouseover, mouseout

I'd like to stop a jQuery animation on mouseover and resume it on mouseout. I thought to use the Pause plugin but it jumps to the next step of the animation. How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
var animation_hamburger = function() {
    $('#inicio #logo .hamburger').animate({ left: 490 },4000);
    $('#inicio #logo .hamburger').animate({ top: 210 },2000);
    $('#inicio #logo .hamburger').animate({ left: -10 },4000);
    $('#inicio #logo .hamburger').animate({ top: -10 },2000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        animation_hamburger();
    },12000);
}
animation_hamburger();
$('#inicio #logo .hamburger').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop();
});
```

You can check the codepen here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeNGxN

Comment: are you interested in jQuery-only solutions or are open to trying out other libraries? take a look at this for example: http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/BjEeGm

Comment: Great, the Tween library solved it :)